# In React 16.x would the useFocusEffect return method that's a promise work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-navigation

I tried to do something like this using React Navigation where

```
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    return () => saveFormAsync(formData)
  }, []));
```

`saveFormAsync` is an `async` method returning a `Promise<void>`.

It seems to work, but I am not sure if I am handling all the cases.

I noted React 16 as [React 17 calls cleanup functions asynchronously](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/06/11/react-17-runs-useeffect-cleanup-asynchronously)

Comment: What's the `useCallback` for?, an effect is kind of already memorised.

Comment: That means something entirely different and is related to how React does things internally. Asynchronous doesn't mean promise.

Comment: @Keith . If you don't wrap your effect in React.useCallback, the effect will run every render if the screen is focused.

Comment: Oh, hang on.  `useFocusEffect`, for some reason I thought it was `useEffect`..

Comment: nope, this is specific for React Navigation